# No vent in my cabin and smell septic tank

Tags: vent, smell, septic, house

I have a cabin without a vent on the roof for the drain pipe.
We have a concrete septic tank also without any vent.
My water drains correctly inside but we have some smell in my bathroom.
Does anybody have a solution for me? Thank you

[image]

Comment: If water is draining good, then you probably have a vent somewhere, out the wall or inside the attic.  Smell can come from leaking pipes, lack of P-traps under drains.

Comment: Please give context to the question.  Is this a cabin you use as your home, or something you use infrequently. If the latter it can just be a situation where the water in the trap/s has dried up.  Is this the first instance or do you always have the smell?

Comment: I use my cabine frequently. We have always some smell sometime more less sometime more. If I have a vent it clearly hidden somewhere in the wall but I'm doubt. It is possible to put a vent somewhere outside between my cabanie and septic tank for vent the smell outside ?

Answer (score 0):

At the level of detail you've provided:

Correct the improper plumbing which is venting sewer gas into your cabin.

Close any vent that opens inside (or extend it to outside, in a proper manner than meets applicable code.)

Put in a proper vent to applicable plumbing code for the location from  the drain plumbing within the cabin to the outside. In most cases this will be through the roof, as non-roof locations are subject to a number of restrictions that are typically difficult to meet (can't be too close to the ground, windows, or vents.)

This will almost certainly require opening up walls for access to correct the plumbing.

While you are at it, be on the lookout for other problems (lack of traps, etc.) since not having a proper vent is a huge plumbing code violation pretty much everywhere, and an indication of poor workmanship by whoever did the plumbing.

*No, you cannot do this correctly between your cabin and septic tank.*